# Mac OSX uninitialized pointer in main function

Tags: c++, c, macos, assembly

I have two questions.

First question. Why does the following code actually work on mac, (compiled with gcc)?

```
int main()
{
    int *p;
    *p = 1;
    return 0;
}
```

When disassembled the line '*p = 1;' becomes

```
mov rax, [rbp - 16]
mov qword [rax], 1
```

Second question. What is located at [rbp - 16]?

While asking the question I interpreted the operand [rbp - 16] as [rbp + 16], which obviously does not make sense. I was tired...

That you for answering my question.

Comment: Before there are a hundred comments along the lines of "undefined behaviour can do anything, including appearing to work", I think it is fairly clear the asker knows this, and wants to know the specifics of why in this particular case it doesn't segfault. **EDIT** Damn, too late.

Comment: @BoBTFish LOL. Isn't that essentially saying the OP wants to know why something that isn't defined to work or not just might favor the former and not the latter? How else can you answer that besides "because thats just the bits roll in UB land on your rig. ?

Comment: And for the OP. `[rbp-16]` is the stack-storage location for your pointer `p` in the `main()` stack frame. (and fwiw, it puked with an access violation on my MBA with Xcode 4.6 and LLVM 4.2).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code has [undefined behaviour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). What this means is that it is permissible for it to do anything at all. It doesn't have to crash.

When your program is starting up, there is code that executes before `main()` and that uses the same stack. What likely happens on your box is that the area of the stack containing `p` had previously been used by another function that kept a valid pointer there. Your `main()` has accidentally stumbled upon that pointer, has dereferenced it, and is corrupting somebody else's memory.

I tried compiling your code using `gcc` and running it on OSX, and it did crash.

Answer (score 1):

As i remember, variables in C are initialized by some value left on stack by previous users - if you don't explicitly specified their values. So, this value is absolutely *random*, and your code just changed value of random memory area. If you get null pointer, your program will fail.

Answer (score 0):

Others have sufficiently covered the undefined-ness of this behavior. Your specific question appeared to be about understanding the disassembly. Here's a somewhat verbose, but hopefully helpful walkthrough:

First instruction: `mov rax, [rbp - 16]`

RBP is the "base pointer register." This holds the address in memory of the current stack frame. As a commenter pointed out `rbp - 16` is the location, in the current stack frame, of `p`. It will be an 8 byte pointer. If you declared another local variable `int *q;` immediately after `p` it's address would likely be at `rbp - 24`. RAX is, in this case, a general purpose register. This copies the 8 byte pointer from where it's situated on the stack at `rbp - 16` into RAX.  As others have pointed out, since you didn't initialize `p`, the value at `rbp - 16` is whatever was left in memory by the last thing to use that memory, or something totally random. The square brackets brackets indicate that the operand `rbp - 16` is a pointer, and that the contents of the memory at the address `rbp - 16` should be copied, and not the literal result of the expression `rbp - 16`. You can think of the expression `rbp - 16` as having the type `int**`.

Second instruction: `mov qword [rax], 1`

QWORD is short for "quad word". Historically, a byte is one byte, a "word" is two bytes, a "long" or "dword" (for 'double word') is four bytes and, naturally, a "quad word" is 8 bytes. This instruction copies a literal 1 (extended to its eight byte form) to the location pointed to by RAX. The square brackets brackets indicate that the operand RAX is a pointer, and that the literal is to be copied into the location *pointed to* by the operand. If the instruction were `mov qword rax, 1` that would copy the literal 1 (in its eight byte form) into RAX.

As others have said, since that pointer is garbage (what ever happened to be in memory) chances are good (but not guaranteed) that this will crash.